# How to change the size of your custom UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I want to use custom view as a toolbar at bottom of my view controller and then design it in my own way. I am using UIView for this purpose and then add as a subview. Somehow, the height of my custom tool bar is not changing. Even, I turned off constraints for it but somehow, it auto adjusts. How can, I do this? Below is my code snippet.

```
//CameraActivity.h class
@interface CameraActivity : UIViewController

//Custom UIView.
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *toolbar;

@end

//CameraActivity.m class, in viewDidLoad.

_toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    [_toolbar removeConstraints:_toolbar.constraints];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 150);
    _toolbar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [_toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:116.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:0.75]];

    [self.view addSubview:_toolbar];
```

Comment: are you use `autolayout`?

Comment: Yes, because I cannot turn it off for one view controller.

Comment: So directly you set the constraint and change that value using `IBOutlet` like `constraint.constant = yourValue`.

Comment: When you add subview, what happens? Does the `UIView` appear on the screen? Where are you changing height of toolbar? Because in the current code you are only initializing with the frame.

Comment: It appears but it's height remains same. I am using autolayout.

Comment: @NimitParekh, IBOutlet means that I need to put UIView and then connect it with IBOutlet.

Comment: Using fix height solves my problem.   CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    _camToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, width, 150);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an outlet of your `UIView` height constraint. Then try to change its height based on device's type as follow:-

In `ViewController.h` file, Create an outlet:-

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeightConstraint;
```

In `ViewController.m` file, Change your height's constraint like this:-

```
if (Device is iPhone 4s) {
    viewHeightConstraint.constant = 30.0;  //Your desired height
}
else if (Device is iPhone 5 || Device is iPhone 5s || Device is iPhone 5c) {
   viewHeightConstraint.constant = 40.0;  //Your desired height
}
else if (Device is iPhone 6) {
   viewHeightConstraint.constant = 50.0;  //Your desired height
}
else if (Device is iPhone 6 Plus) {
   viewHeightConstraint.constant = 60.0;  //Your desired height
}
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: I highly recommend not using hardcoded values for different screensizes, but rather size classes, or screen height %.

Comment: But if your sizes are going to remain same then there should not be any issues in giving hard coded values.

Comment: In theory yes. In practice, shit changes all the time. This kind of code is unmaintainable. Imagine you have 10 views like this one, and one day, its size will change. Imagine a new iPhone size appears. Imagine the app has to be ported on iPad. Wether its the OP or someone else looking for help, this solution is a nightmare.

Comment: then what can be the fisible solution apart from this? Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Like i said in my first comment, screensize % in constraints is an easy task. Add an "Equal height" constraint between the view and its superview, then set a multiplier of "0.2" for a size of 20% of its superview. Size classes are also an option but they're a bit more complex

Answer (score 0):

Before creating (i.e `_toolbar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];`)  your view `toolbar`, using it will cause this issue.

Hence, change the line order to this :

```
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 150);
_toolbar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
_toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[_toolbar removeConstraints:_toolbar.constraints];
[_toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:116.0/255.0 green:174.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:0.75]];
[self.view addSubview:_toolbar];
```

Also I suggest setting frame must done in 
    `-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews` beacause `viewDidLoad` is not a good place for this! so,

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{
 _toolbar.frame  = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 150);

}
```

Comment: Adding this in viewDidLayoutSubviews makes my navigation bar disappears. The height still remains same. Did you run the code on your computer?

Comment: @WasimSafdar Nope! I

Comment: Okay. Check my and @Nirmit answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I added UIView from objects library instead of adding it programmatically and then sets its width according to screen width of device and height to constant. Also assigned some constraints solve my problem. [image: Constraints need to be set]

```
//CameraActivity.h class
@interface CameraActivity : UIViewController

//This time not custom UIView but IBOutlet.
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *toolbar;

@end

//CameraActivity.m class
#import "CameraActivity.h"
@implementation CameraActivity

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Get your device screen width.
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    _toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, width, 150);
}
```